# RFID Tag, Xbee or Bluetooth Module

Tags: rfid, bluetooth-low-energy, xbee

I am just trying to detect if an object is within 7-10 feet from my phone. What device would you recommend?
I don't care where it is or anything I just need a way of detecting that that device is at least 10 feet away from me...

Comment: shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: What if you are not carrying your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth low energy seems like the best technology for that.